# chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia Can't capture self window

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, screensharing

I've written an application(webrtc screen sharing), everything is ok with `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` if you pick another window to share but if you pick chrome window(self) to share it gives you just empty stream.

No error just nothing. Is this a known bug? Or any solution this? Is there any way to disband chrome window from windows list at least?

Edit: hardware acceleration enabling/disabling doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please paste the code you are using to trigger the Chrome Screenshare selection window? and how you use `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia`?

Comment: Also when you mean chrome window, you mean you are sharing an Application instead of the full screen, and in this case is the Chrome tab itself, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a single application to be listed in the windows list. You can disable the whole option. This would mean you won't be able to share any application.
You can customize this when calling `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia`, sending the set of desktop media sources you will allow to select when sharing:
`"screen", "window", "tab", or "audio"`

Check this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) for more details.

If you could provide some code on how are you using Chrome API to share the screen that would be great to be able to provide more details on how you can solve your issue.